# TypeError: server.of is not a function while using socket.io namespace with nestjs

Tags: typescript, socket.io, nestjs, typeerror

I want to emit events across socket.io's namespaces and i got this type error:

```
backend     |       this.chatNamespace = io.of("chat");
backend     |                           ^
backend     | TypeError: io.of is not a function
```

here is my original code. what did i get wrong?

```
@WebSocketGateway(3000, {
    cors : 'http://localhost',
    namespace : 'game',
})
export class GameGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection{

    @WebSocketServer() 
    server : Server;
        
    chatNamespace : Namespace;
    
    async afterInit(io : Server) {
        this.chatNamespace = io.of("chat");
    }

    async handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        console.log("hello i'm game user!");
        this.chatNamespace.emit("sendMessage", "game", "hihi");
        client.emit("gameHello", "hello gamer!");
    }
}
```

i have no idea why i got this error because i could see the class Server has method "of" and it's return type is Namespace.

I also tried changing io and chatNamespace's types as any but error message was the same

--

solved! for anyone who encounter same problem :

```
@WebSocketGateway({
    namespace: 'game',
    pingTimeout: 2000,
    pingInterval: 5000,
})
export class GameGateway
    implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayInit
{
    @WebSocketServer() //you need this decorator to use namespace!
    io : Namespace;

    //this.io.server.of('chat') <- now you can access to another namespace 'chat' like this
    ...
}
```

or you can write like this :

```
//be careful!
//don't state namespace here to use io.of('someNamespace')
@WebSocketGateway() 
export class Gateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection{
  @WebSocketServer()
  io : Server;

  @WebSocketServer()
  game : Namespace;

  @WebSocketServer()
  chat : Namespace;

  afterInit(){
    this.game = this.io.of("/game");
    this.chat = this.io.of("/chat");
  }

  handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
    this.game.emit("sendGameHi");
    this.chat.emit("sendChatHi");
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: yes:P you should put @WebSocketServer() decorator to a namespace as well
like this `@WebSocketServer() io: Namespace;`
or you can access another namespace like this : `this.io.server.of('anotherNamespace')`